# array_map with two different classes?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-map

I am trying to do the PHP alternative to this Javascript function.

```
async.map items, (item, done) =>
    async.map [
        @engine.likes
        @engine.dislikes
    ], (rater, done) =>
        rater.usersByItem item, done
    , done
, (err, others) =>
```

I've managed to do it with one version of the class.

```
    $likes = new Rater('likes');
    $dislikes = new Rater('dislikes');

    $others = array_map( function($value) use ($likes){
        return $likes->users_by_game($value);
        }, $items );
```

Is there a way to do it all in one go or is it not possible with PHP?

Comment: what is `async`?

Comment: you could combine the 2 lists....

Comment: This is async https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map and I did wonder about just merging both once they are done. Just wondered if it was possible as it would be cleaner code to do it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do something like

```
$raters = [new Rater('likes'), new Rater('dislikes')];

$others = array_map(function($item) use ($raters) {

    return array_map(function ($rater) use ($item) {

        return $rater->users_by_game($item);

    },  $raters);

}, $items);
```

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I wanted :) Thank you!!

Comment: @Kyon147 Nice. Note: that `async.map` does not guarantee order, whereas PHP's `map` does. If you care about order, use `async.mapSeries`.

Comment: Thanks, @Mikey really appreciate it. Been racking my brain trying to figure out the logic.